# appendAttributedString return value of type Void

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to append two `NSAttributedString`.

```
let string_1 : NSAttributedString = self.answerTextView.attributedText
let string_2 : NSAttributedString = handleHtml(i) // a function that returns a NSAttributedString
let finalStr : NSAttributedString = string_1.mutableCopy().appendAttributedString(string_2)
```

But I got an error at the third line:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Void' (aka '()') to specified type 'NSAttributedString'

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`appendAttributedString` updates the caller. It doesn't return a new string. Try the following:

```
let string_1 : NSAttributedString = self.answerTextView.attributedText
let string_2 : NSAttributedString = handleHtml(i) // a function that returns a NSAttributedString
let tmpStr : NSMutableAttributedString = string_1.mutableCopy()
tmpStr.appendAttributedString(string_2)
let finalStr : NSAttributedString = tmpStr.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Def something like this:

```
//MARK: Custom functions
func getQueueAttributedString(number N: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let uploadSymbolAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UEColor.brown.six, NSFontAttributeName: UEFont.unearthCharacterFont(13)]

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: UEFontCharacter.triangle_up, attributes: uploadSymbolAttributes)

    let queueAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UEColor.brown.six, NSFontAttributeName: UEFont.museo300(withSize: 13)]

    let queueString = NSAttributedString(string: " \(N) items queued", attributes: queueAttributes)

    attributedString.append(queueString)

    return attributedString

}
```

Where `UEFont` is a custom `UIFont`, `UEColor` is a static struct of custom `UIColor`'s and `UEFontCharacter` are linear icon fonts.